# what does xargs du -h do?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, xargs

the command is

```
find /etc -type f | xargs du -h
```

I know that it basically means find all files in /etc but I'm not too sure on what the du -h does to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

du gives you the disk usage.

The -h switch shows the disk usage in human-readable format.

See http://linux.die.net/man/1/du

Answer (score 0):

The `du` command reports on disk usage.  The `-h` option prints in human units (e.g. 2.0K for 2 KiB).